# pass data from code behind to jquery dialog

Tags: asp.net

I am using below code to show jquery dialog, its working perfectly,

```
Sub OpenDialog(ByVal dialogId As String)
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, [GetType](), "openDialog", "$('#newPerson').dialog('open');", True)
End Sub
```

problem is that i wanted to pass some data from codebehind, i am using repeater control and binding repeater before opening dialog. it doesnt show any data on first click, when i click twice it show data in repeater control. any suggestion would be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Sorry dear, I couldn't understand, your issue is to pass data from code behind to jquery or repeater not showing data against first click?

Comment: Hi Imran
Actually i am trying to pass datatable to jquery dialog which i am displaying dynamically, when i click button it displays dialog but it is not getting binded with repeater, if i again press same button then it displays data in repeater control. 
Regards

Comment: against which event you are binding data with repeater control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use asp hidden fields,
Set there values in back end using this

```
HiddenField1.Value = "Your data";
```

& get them in JavaScript using this

```
document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>');
```